# What is the correct use of "never" when using present perfect

Tags: grammar

I'm writing a short story and a friend corrected my use of the present perfect.

I wrote: "The painting summoned emotions she HAS never felt before".

He suggested: "The painting summoned emotions she HAD never felt before".

My short story is written in the present tense, so I am inclined to stick with my variant. However, I am now unsure since English is not my native language (it is my friend's).

P.S.: I'm having a difficult time finding a better title for this question. Suggestions are welcome :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My short story is written in the present tense

Is it?

> The painting summon**ed** emotions...

This isn't present, therefore your friend is right: the subordinate clause should be in past perfect.

Comment: Ah. Right :). And yes, the story is written in the present tense, but in this sentence, a past event is referred to, so yes, I should be consistent. Side-question: is my use of the present perfect correct here? "She has never been so afraid, doesn’t dare ask what he read."

Comment: @Axonn: yes, that one looks fine